# What is the recommended way to protect a TeX Live file from updates with no changes or to auto-patch it on such updates?

Tags: packages, texlive, perl, tlmgr, texdef

Many package managers allow users to prevent certain packages from being updated. Often this is called 'pinning'. A pinned package is protected from automatic updates. This is useful, for example, if a bug in a package is problematic on a particular system and is modified or down-graded locally until fixed upstream. Since the package may get other updates before the fix, preventing updates protects the pinned version until a newer version with the relevant fix becomes available.

`tlmgr` supports something called 'pinning' but it pins a package to a repository rather than protecting it from updates *per se*.

As things currently stand, `texdef.pl` requires patching to work with current perl. There is no evidence whatsoever that this is likely to be fixed in the foreseeable future. Hence, I need a patched version indefinitely.

[Details and patch: [How can I avoid this regex error when attempting to use texdef?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/377168/how-can-i-avoid-this-regex-error-when-attempting-to-use-texdef)]

However, every time I update TeX Live, my patched version is overwritten by the original, even though the original version has not changed in anyway. That is, it isn't that the distributed version has been updated, but not, sadly, with the fixes I need. It hasn't changed at all. But `tlmgr` insists on replacing my working version with TeX Live's broken one, even though that version is buggy and older.

There are various things I could do about this. For example, I could change the permissions so that it required root privileges to overwrite the patched version. This would work, but I suspect that it would cause `tlmgr` to exit with a four-letter complaint about the state of its world.

If the file were a `.sty` or similar, I could install the patched version in TEXMFLOCAL or TEXMFHOME. Unfortunately, it's a script, sym-linked from the binaries directory, so `kpsewhich` isn't being used to access it and I can't work around it that way.

There are various other tricks I could use involving shell aliases and so on, but this is quite involved and relatively fragile. Moreover, the number of users experiencing this problem is going to increase as more users get current versions of perl. So it would be nice if there was a more 'official' and robust solution.

Is it possible to 'pin' a package or file using `tlmgr` so that it is not overwritten on update? Ideally, something which prints a reminder to the console that it is being skipped, but that's icing and I'm mostly concerned here with cake.

If not, what is the best approach to this? It is getting really annoying having to keep patching the bloody file when the damned thing is identical to the buggy version I fixed last time I updated ... and the time before ... and the time before that ....

I suppose I could make a local one-package repository for it. However, that seems a very awkward way to achieve what is surely a pretty straightforward goal.

Comment: Good question, but the actual solution would be to fix `texdef.pl` in upstream.

Comment: @HenriMenke As mentioned, it seems that is not going to happen in the foreseeable future. This is an easy fix. The author knows about the problem. The author knows the fix. The author has been asked to fix it. There's no sign of it happening. Realistically, as opposed to ideally, another strategy is needed.

Comment: Why not just write the CTAN maintainers an email and ask them to just place the fix?  We cannot just keep broken software on CTAN and try to monkey-patch the way packages are distributed.

Comment: If it is this package: https://bitbucket.org/martin_scharrer/texdef , it seems unmaintained. I don't remember, but isn't there a way how to deal with unmaintained packages?

Comment: I suggest to ask on the texlive list.

Comment: I think if you uninstall the texdef package, then it will not get reinstalled/updated in the future, but I am still on 2016, so cannot test. If that works, you then just need to manually install the texdef package so tlmgr does not know about it.

Comment: There is no such functionality by now in tlmgr, and I'm not sure whether I want to implement a similar functionality.

Comment: @norbert Unpatched `texdef` hasn't worked for me for months. I can jury-rig something, but the number of people for whom it doesn't work is only going to increase. This could be fixed, but there is a general issue here since, in other cases, it might not be possible to provide something which works for everyone. If, say, the change required to a script was not compatible with earlier versions of the interpreter or whatever. I don't know. I've never given it much thought before, as I didn't realise the function wasn't there until I tried to use it.

Comment: The changes are minimal and could be included in TL, we have them in Debian since long. Best would be to upload to CTAN a fixed version.

Comment: @norbert But who can do that? (Other than the author, I mean.)

Comment: Upload everyone can do, but you need to give a good explanation why you upload it, including the fact that it is not maintained, and maybe the changes you made. It is up to CTAN maintainers, though.

Comment: @norbert I believe that it is officially maintained. The maintainer just hasn't fixed it.

Comment: I think it is now updated

Comment: @norbert Thanks. However, I still think there's a general issue here: what if the change in syntax required was not backwards compatible? TL relies on the system's libraries and has no guarantee they'll be the same everywhere. However, it isn't something I'd urge anyone to put any time into so long as the problem remains a largely hypothetical one. (Excepting `texdef`, where a fix could have been implemented, as backwards compatibility is fine.)

Comment: Well, what do you suggest besides an option to force packages at a fixed version, which can already be done with the --exclude cmd line option!?

Comment: @norbert A config file equivalent of exclude. At least, I couldn't find a way to do this via the config file.

Comment: @cfr it is now here, should bin in `tltesting` starting with tomorrow. The key is named `update-exclude` and is a comma-separated string of package names, similar to the `update --exclude` cmf line switch. Hope that helps.

Comment: @norbert Thank you! Yes, that sounds like exactly the feature I was looking for and could not find. Can you turn your comment into an answer I can accept, please?

Comment: @norbert Is it updated but not yet released? (Not yet in TeX Live, that is?) See https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7464/list-of-perl-scripts-that-have-fixed-the-unescaped-literal-character-problem/7465?noredirect=1#comment22263_7465 where it is reported that unpatched `texdef` still fails with a just-updated TL 2017.

Comment: It is still in tlcritical, but push out should happen soon.

Comment: @cfr, all: Sorry, that it took so long to publish the easy fix, however, I never got told that it causes an *error*. At the beginning it was just an annoying warning. If I would have got many emails again, not just one or two during a time I was very busy, I would have certainly have fixed it sooner. Before thinking about contacting the CTAN maintainers why not drop another email to the author?  Or better: use the official bug tracker: the official bug report dates 2017-11-04 and it got fixed on 2017-12-09. (Yes, the fix patch was already around way longer ...)

Comment: @MartinScharrer I did send an email. I didn't know about the bug tracker.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned in [nobert's comment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/388721/what-is-the-recommended-way-to-protect-a-tex-live-file-from-updates-with-no-chan#comment982612_388721), packages can now be 'pinned' by adding them in a comma-separated list

```
update-exclude = \
<package1-name>,\
<package2-name>,\
... etc.
```

to `texmf.cnf`.